# Using integration by parts to solve a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on the following analysis problem.

Suppose that $u\in C([a,b])$ is twice continuously differentiable, $V\in C([a,b])$, $V(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and

$$ -u''(x)+V(x)u(x)=0, \forall x\in[a,b]$$

$$u(a)=u(b)=0$$

Show that $u(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

The hint tells me to use integration by parts to solve this problem, but I can't see where to use it.

I tried the following, but it doesn't lead to a meaningful result.

Let $v(x)=\int_a^x V(t)dt$. Then, integrating by parts, we have

$$ \int_a^b V(x)u(x)dx = v(b)u(b)-v(a)u(a)-\int_a^bv(x)u'(x)dx = -\int_a^bv(x)u'(x)dx $$

and because $u''(x)=V(x)u(x)$,

$$\int_a^bV(x)u(x)dx = \int_a^bu''(x)dx = u'(b)-u'(a) = -\int_a^bv(x)u'(x)dx $$

I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me where to use the integration by parts in this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general 'trick' is to use the fact that $-\Delta = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is a positive operator on the space of differentiable functions, square integrable and vanishing at the boundary.

$$\int_a^b u(x)(-u''(x)) dx = \int_a^b u'(x)^2  dx > 0 $$
but
$$\int_a^b  V(x)u(x)^2 dx>0 $$
too, so u=0.

Geometrical background: A solution $u: x\to u(x)$ starting with a zero on the left boundary with slope $u'(a)>0$ and $u''> 0 $ everywhere, has a positive slope everywhere and cannot bend down to yield a zero on the upper boundary.